# Stack in C, how to

Tags: c, stack

```
struct stack
{
    int value;
    struct stos *w;

};

struct stack *pnt;
struct stack *prev;

void push(value);
void delete(struct stack *new);
void print_stack();
void push(int x)
{
    prev = pnt;
    pnt = (struct stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
    pnt->value=x;
    pnt->w = prev;
    printf("Top of stack: %d\n", pnt->value);
}

void delete(struct stack *new)
{
    if (new!=NULL)
    {
        prev = new->w;
        printf("Deleted: %d\n", new->value);
        free(new);
        pnt = prev;
    }
    else printf("Stack is empty\n");
}

void print_stack()
{
    printf("Content of stack:\n");
    prev = pnt;
    while (prev!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", prev->value);
        prev = prev->w;
    }
}
```

I have a question about the pointers there. Not what every pointer means (probably means top of stack) but what is meant by  'prev' and 'pnt'.
I just don't get it at all. 'Prev' maybe is a previous value of stack?
Maybe somebody can show me a picture.

Comment: It will be better to use Google..

Comment: `struct stos` ??

Comment: @Weather Vane my bad, edited

Comment: Why don't you trace the code? There are, however, a lot of problems with it; what is `stos`, why no `pop()`, why isn't `prev` a local variable, etc?

Comment: How could you have written this code if you don't understand it?  Do you have the author's permission to publish this code under the Creative Commons license used by this website?

Comment: @KenY-N im not a experienced "programmer" and I still need a lot to learn, so name of delete() is better as pop() or what? Why prev must me a local variable?

Comment: @paddy at all it's not copied, I used a lot of "tutorials" on Internet to write it, but I did it about 3-4 months ago and on Thursday I have test, so I want to understand it.

Comment: `push()` and `pop()` are the two main operations on a stack; `delete()` makes little sense. `prev` being local is not a *must*, but a *should*, as its value only makes sense within the scope of a single function.

Comment: There's a valuable lesson here about code comments and appropriate variable names.

Comment: @KenY-N so should I in every function add `struct stack *prev;`?

Comment: Yes, that would be better IMO. (Actually, `prev_tos`, `new_tos` and `current` in that order would be more descriptive names.) Note that `pop()` should be roughly `int pop() { int val = pnt->value; delete(pnt); return val; }`. Also rename `pnt` to `tos` (*T*op *o*f *s*tack) or something similar, so as @paddy hints at, when you revisit the code another 3 or 4 months later you can more easily understand what is going on.

Comment: @KenY-N But for this 3-4 months I haven't used C, I haven't write too much. Should I use more returns than void functions, less printfs in functions, more returns, yep?

Comment: No, my question was not why you passed `stos` to `void delete(struct stos *new)`, as you have now edited in the question, but where `struct stos` which is a member of `struct stack` is defined? Please do not fumble with the posted code.

Comment: Talking about naming conventions - you don't call container's elements with the container's name. So stack's elements shouldn't be called "stack". "Stack" is the container and the elements should be named "element" or something like that. It's like "Tree" & "Node", "List" & "Link".

Answer (score 1):

pnt is a pointer, as declared by,

```
struct stack *pnt;
struct stack *prev;
```

it points to a stack struck declared by

```
struct stack
{
    int value;
    struct stos *w; // struct stos should struct stack

};
```

You are missing this declaration from the other code.

```
typedef struct stos{

    int value;
    struct stos *next; 

} stos;
```

So, this is lifted code that has problems, a lot of problems...

Let us begin

First fix the stos mess:

The problems the two structs above were lifted (copied/pasted) so instead of the `struct stack` containing a pointer to same type of structure is looking for an undefined structure `struct stos *next;` it should be `struct stack* next;`

```
typedef struct Stack;
typedef struct stack {

    int value;
    Stack* next;

} Stack;

struct stack *pnt; // pnt = pointer top of stack
struct stack *prev; // prev = pointer to the previous stack item
```

So now we know the stack is kept as a singularly linked list of stack structs.

Let's decipher `void push(int x)`

```
void push(int x)
{
    // point prev to pnt, previous to top of stack
    prev = pnt; 

    // create a new item to place on the top of the stack
    pnt = (struct stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct stack)); 

    // initial the value member of the new item with x
    pnt->value=x;

    // point the new item's link point to point the previous top of the stack
    pnt->w = prev; 

    // print the value contained in the new top of the stack item.
    printf("Top of stack: %d\n", pnt->value); 
}
```

This function is a disaster because it use the keyword `new` as the name of a variable. Yes, `new` is in C++. But why make a mess of things for the next person.

```
void delete(struct stos *new)
{
    if (new!=NULL)
    {
        prev = new->w;
        printf("Deleted: %d\n", new->value);
        free(new);
        pnt = prev;
    }
    else printf("Stack is empty\n");
}
```

Should have been written as follows...

```
    // forward declaration of Stos because it won't be defined until the end of struct it is used in.

typedef struct  {

    int value;
    struct Stack* next;

} Stack;


Stack* pnt; // pnt = pointer top of stack
Stack* prev; // prev = pointer to the previous stack item
```

Using `Stack* pnt` versus `Stack *pnt` says, "A Stack pointer called pnt" versus "A pointer called pnt which points to Stacks". (There is also a spiral trick to read these declarations easier Q.E.D)

```
void delete( Stack* pNew)
{
    if ( pNew )
    {
        prev = pNew->w;
        printf("Deleted: %d\n", pNew->value);
        free(pNew);
        pnt = prev;
    }
    else printf("Stack is empty\n");
}
```

As I said, this is a mess. 
What is important is you asked a question and hopefully have learned a few things that will help you on your next piece of code.

1. once you create a typedef, then use it. drop the `struct stack` stuff
2. make the names of variables long enough so that future readers will understand the code `Stack* pTopOfStack;`
3. try not to use words that are keywords in derivatives `new`
4. Don't over crowd the code with redundant code

`if ( new != NULL )` versus `if ( new )`, even better `if ( pNewStackItem )`

Better to fully understand what the code is doing instead of complicating it with more stuff that looks right, compiles and runs. Never trust a programmer, "sorry, it works on my machine."

Comment: what about `Stack* next` it's pointer of next item which we are taking into stack?

Comment: @Vanderdecken  struct Stack and struct stack are two different types. Moreover struct Stack is incomplete type.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yep, compiler gave mi some errors... So where is problem there, because I have now: "unknown type name Stack". I tried to `typedef struct Stack;
typedef struct
{
 int value;
 Stack* next;
} Stack;

Stack* first;
Stack* last;`

Comment: @Dr.Weiss There is no need to introduce new type struct Stack. Just define struct stack
{
    int value;
    struct stack *w;

};

Comment: @Dr.Weiss Also the function delete does not make sense. If you are dealing with a stack you have access only to the top of the stack. So the parameter of the function does not make sense provided that the top of the stack is defined as a global variable and the function push does not have a parameter.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow delete function should be without parameter there? How to make that struct well with typedef? Because I'm trying a lot of ways and still "unknown type name stack" in stack* next;

Comment: @Dr.Weiss With a typedef the structure can look like typedef struct stack { int value; struct stack *next; } stack;

Comment: Okay, I edited the typedef struct Stack code and it works now.  Again, my point being, this is code that has real problems because was not written, it was copied and pasted together instead of understanding the solution to the given problem. This is may not be the best way to implement the solution. That is not my job here do the homework of others.

Comment: I'm giving your props for the help here.  Thanks for taking the time to show them many of the issues.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan, thank you. My life's work is about solving problems by helping people solve their own problems.